# docker-compose healthcheck not working for neo4j docker

Tags: neo4j, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that boots up several containers. I'd like to circumvent the error messages I'm currently seeing so that the other docker container only fire up once the neo4j container is running. Right now, I have:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  neo4j:
    container_name: neo4j 
    hostname: neo4j 
    image: neo4j:3.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=2G
      - dbms_connector_bolt_tls__level=OPTIONAL
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=3500M
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/start
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/import:/import
      - $HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:7474/", "||", "exit 1"] 
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10
  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    hostname: myapp
    image: python:3.7.3-slim
    build: './APP'
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

The `healthcheck` parameter makes no difference. I also used:

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:7474 2>&1 | grep -c -e '200 OK'
```

and...

```
["CMD-SHELL", "/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j status"]
```

At the moment my myapp tries to load up then exits, until the neo4j is running. How can I make myapp wait till neo4j is running?

Comment: Here is what I use for health check: https://gist.github.com/fbiville/bf617f29a18b1ecc688bf312915d83f1#file-docker-start-sh-L42. Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

You are indeed looking for `depends_on` BUT only when the service is healthy. This means the docker-compose file has to look like the following:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  myapp:
    ...
    depends_on:
      # Make sure the application only starts when the DB is indeed ready
      neo4j:
        condition: service_healthy

  neo4j:
     ...
     healthcheck:
      test: wget http://localhost:7474 || exit 1
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 20
      start_period: 3s
```

Comment: This fixed my issue too.  Somewhat naively, perhaps, I had assumed that `depends_on` pointing to a service with a `healthcheck` would depend on the service being 'healthy'

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `depends_on` annotation.

On your particular case:

```
myapp:
  ...
  depends_on: 
    - "neo4j"
```

You can find detailed information here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: I originally had this, but it didn't work and doesn't apply to docker-compose version 3.x, I believe